# Customize word definition in Vim?

Tags: vim

How can I customize word definition in Vim? The default is a series of character like `_`,`[a-zA-Z]` are considered as word. I'd like to add some other chars to this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `iskeyword` setting.

Read the [VIM docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#iskeyword) for it or see [this woss article](https://woss.name/articles/vim-iskeyword/) for an example.